# Two cars are connected to a string, parked on a slope. What happens?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

I would like to ask something, which I would expect to have the same answer as the one to my previous question. But I'd like to be sure and further my understanding: [A mass is hanging by a thread from another mass, which starts to fall. What happens and why?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/797729/)

So please consider the following situation: Car A and car B are parked on a slope with some distance D between them. Car B (placed lower on the slope) is connected by a wire to car A. Car A is connected by another string to a pole, higher up along the slope. All strings are fully stretched. So the system is at rest.

Now, the string connecting car A to the pole is cut. (Cars A and B are still connected by a different string). Things start to slide down the slope.

What will happen?

1. Both cars will start sliding down the hill more-or-less at the same time (car B slightly later than car A)?
2. Car A will start to slide down, and collide with car B, which will stay put until the collision.
3. Something else.

Comment: Wether the cars slide is a matter of friction, which you haven't given to us information on, and since the cars are *parked* they shouldn't go anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A mass is hanging by a thread from another mass, which starts to fall. What happens and why?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/797729/)

Comment: This scenario is not qualitatively any different from masses hanging on a string. The behavior comes down to whether you treat the string as an inextensible massless string which can propagate forces from end-to-end instantaneously, or if it's a real string where forces take time to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

Both cars will start to slide when string of car $A$ and pole is cut (given that friction is not large enough to keep them at rest) at the exact same time because the gravitational force is acting on both of them all throughout the duration of observation. So gravitation pulla them also the moment the first string is cut. Note that both masses accelerate at the same rate of $g\sin\theta$ if there is no friction where $\theta$ is the angle of elevation. Even if there is friction, they have same acceleration of $g(\mu\cos\theta - \sin\theta)$ where $\mu$ is *coefficient of friction* as long as $\theta$ and $\mu$ remain constant.

This means the cars will **not** collide and the string connecting them will be slack during the motion. The same string between cars $A$ and $B$ was **taut** when car $A$ was attached to the pole.

Comment: However, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/797764/186017.